# What is the point of the second "T" in a function?

Tags: java, android

Here is an example:

```
public static <T extends ViewDataBinding> T bind(@NonNull View root) {
    return bind(root, sDefaultComponent);
}
```

T is the class extending `ViewDataBinding`, but why is there another `T`?

Comment: Do you mean the one before `bind`? That's the return type of the method. The `<T extends ViewDataBinding>` effectively declares the type parameter - that type parameter could be used anywhere in the method signature.

Comment: Inside the diamond is the type parameter, outside is the return type.

Comment: So it's the return type. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`<T extends ViewDataBinding>` part defines the constraints the T must meet. I all other places you then just referer to such defined type.